# Validate a linkedin access token server side

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, linkedin-api

I need to validate a linkedin access token on server side, also i need to know if the token is valid for my app. I've tryied with:
 {https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN}    , but this obviously works with all valid tokens. I need to check also if the token is valid for my app.. is there a way to do that with linkedin api?